# Summation of piecewise functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, piecewise

I have function `y`, whish is the sum of piecewise functions `f0_basis` and `f1_basis` (defined on `[r_i-1; r_i+1]`), multipled by number coefficients alpha and beta:

```
y=@(r) 0;    
for j=1:1:N
    y1= @(r) f0_basis(r ,j).*alpha(j)+f1_basis(r ,j).*beta(j);
    y=@(r) y1(r)+y(r);

end
fplot(y,[a,b])
```

The `fplot` gives me what I want (`a=1` and `b=1.1`):

[image]

However when I try, to find the value of `y(r_i)` - it always gives me the same wrong result for (`a<r_i<b`)

> y(r_i)=-0.0016

which doesnt reperesents the plot above. Though if I try `y(a)` and `y(b)` - it gives me the right result.

What is wrong? I want to simply create an array `y_array(i) = y(r_i)`.

```
  N=11
  a=1; b=1.1
  delta_r=(b-a)/(N-1)
  r_grid(i)=a+delta_r.*(i-1);


function y=f0_basis(r ,i)%i - номер середины узла
    ri=r_grid(i);
    r1=ri-delta_r;
    r2=ri+delta_r;

    y1=(2*((r-ri)/delta_r).^3-3*((r-ri)/delta_r).^2+1).*(r>=ri & r<=r2 & r2<=b);%правый конец
    y2=(-2*((r-r1)/delta_r).^3+3*((r-r1)/delta_r).^2).*(r>=r1 & r<=ri & r1>=a);%левый конец
    y3=0;%в сотальных случаях
    y=y1+y2+y3;
end

function y=f1_basis(r ,i)%ri - середина узла
   ri=r_grid(i);
   r1=ri-delta_r;
   r2=ri+delta_r;

   r_div_1=(r-ri)/delta_r;
   r_div_2=(r-r1)/delta_r;

    y1=delta_r*(r_div_1.^3-2*(r_div_1.^2)+r_div_1).*(r>=ri & r<=r2 & r2<=b);%правый конец
    y2=delta_r*(r_div_2.^3-r_div_2.^2).*(r>=r1 & r<=ri & r1>=a);%левый конец
    y3=0;%в сотальных случаях
    y=y1+y2+y3;
end

Alpha:
-0,000828144527478242
-0,000823822186226137
-0,000819532164240625
-0,000815314580859248
-0,000811187867518122
-0,000807162471718638
-0,000803245019928998
-0,000799439804012876
-0,000795750103056819
-0,000792175886650016
-0,000788726122705251

Beta:
-1,14781261976785e-05
-0,00257727396861173
-0,000627562853139588
0,000211869596648955
0,000683549308474220
0,000987694942326156
0,00119967671089174
0,00136043282028271
0,00145954455875083
0,00163805699746171
-0,000147024199470849
```

**UPDATE:**
it seems that `y(r_i)=-0.0016` for only `r_grid(i)` array. If I try some r not from `r_grid(i)` array - it works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `y = y + y1(r)`, where `r` is a variable maybe in the outer for loop. Also, `y = 0` instead of `y = @(r) 0`. This means, for any value of `r`, `y(r) = 0`.

Comment: Can you give a (simplified) sample of what are `f0_basis`, `f1_basis`, `alpha` and `beta`, in order to be able to run the code?

Comment: @Bentoy13 yeah, updated post.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the functions `f0_basis` and `f1_basis`. You compute 2 terms inside each function (the 3rd one is null), each term is subject to some constraints. But the constraints are overlapping for one point, if `r==ri`. In this case, you are adding two equal terms, but nowhere else. That's why you have strange results at `r_grid(i)`.

So change the tests, for example `r>=r1 & r<ri & r1>=a` for `y2`.

Comment: @AntonMashikhin Please accept the answer if you think it answers the OP.